# Why Redux action is not Being being dispatched in Redux-Tooklit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using react-redux with redux and redux-toolkit. And according to this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-counter-example/tree/master/?file=/src/features/counter/counterSlice.js), i created an async dispatch that calls the reducer action when resolved.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const BlogSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Blog",
  initialState: {
    BlogList: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    getBlogList: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      state.BlogList = action.payload;
    }
  },
});

export const { getBlogList } = BlogSlice.actions;

export const getBlogListAsync = (user_id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(`/api/blog/getblogs/${user_id}`).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch(getBlogList(res.data.result));
  });
};

export const selectBlogList = (state) => state.Blog.BlogList;
export default BlogSlice.reducer;
```

I have used it in a component accordingly so that, the component dispatches `getBlogListAsync` and that logs the `res.data` but getBlogList is not being dispatched. I tried putting other `console.log()` but don't understand what is wrong.

A similar Slice is working perfectly with another Component.

Comment: can you share a demo in https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say for sure what's wrong here because there is nothing that is *definitely* wrong.

#### `res.data.result`?

You are logging `res.data` and then setting the blog list to `res.data.result`.  My best guess as to your mistake is that `res.data.result` is not the the correct property for accessing the blogs, but I can't possibly know that without seeing your API.

```
console.log(res.data);
dispatch(getBlogList(res.data.result));
```

#### missing middleware?

Is there any chance that "thunk" middleware is not installed?  If you are using Redux Toolkit and omitting the middleware entirely, then the thunk middleware will be installed by default.  Also if this were the case you should be getting obvious errors, not just nothing happening.

#### it seems fine...

I tested out your code with a placeholder API and I was able to get it working properly.  Maybe this code helps you identify the problem on your end.  [Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-fetch-blogs-vognk?file=/src/App.tsx).

```
import React from "react";
import { createSlice, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const BlogSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Blog",
  initialState: {
    BlogList: null
  },
  reducers: {
    getBlogList: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      state.BlogList = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { getBlogList } = BlogSlice.actions;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    Blog: BlogSlice.reducer
  }
});

export const getBlogListAsync = (user_id) => (
  dispatch: Dispatch
) => {
  // your url `/api/blog/getblogs/${user_id}`
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${user_id}`; // placeholder URL
  axios.get(url).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    // your list: res.data.result <-- double check this
    const list = res.data; // placeholder list
    dispatch(getBlogList(list));
  });
};

export const selectBlogList = (state) => state.Blog.BlogList;

const Test = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const blogs = useSelector(selectBlogList);

  const user_id = "1";

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(getBlogListAsync(user_id))}>
        Load Blogs
      </button>
      <h3>Blog Data</h3>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(blogs)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Test />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I figured out the mistake that I made and that was really stupid one. I didn't dispatched the action rather just called the action. I am guilty about that and I am really sorry for inconvenience and your time. I might remove the question.